# Android Studio crash after camera intent in real device (virtual emulator is working fine)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crash, runtime-error, android-camera

This is my code about Android upload image using Android Studio. My apps crash  after capturing image (the apps was stopped working) but it is doing fine in virtual emulator (same API 19), and the logcat tell me *an error occur while executing doing background*. Can someone help me find out my mistake?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    getFileUri();
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,file_uri);
                    startActivityForResult(i,10);
                }
            });
        }
    private void getFileUri() {
            image_name = "testing123.jpg";
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    +File.separator + image_name);
            file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
             if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
             {
                new Encode_image().execute();
             }
        }


        private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
                byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
                encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array,0);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                makeRequest();
            }
        }

        private void makeRequest() {
            RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://mygplobang.com/tut_connection.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
                    map.put("image_name",image_name);

                    return map;
                }
            };
            requestqueue.add(request);
        }
```

This is the error output:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.jeffreykhang.kas, PID: 6879
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                                                       at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.jeffreykhang.kas.MainActivity$Encode_image.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:93)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.jeffreykhang.kas.MainActivity$Encode_image.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:90)
>                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: what do u have in line 93 in MainActivity? Makesure nothing is null in doInBackground

Comment: hi Raghavendra, the line 90 is private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{, and line 93 is bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());

Comment: then I guess file_uri is null. Please do a null check

Comment: i am new in android , can u gv me a null  check example , at where do i locate the null check ?  , at  protected void onCreate{}  ?

Comment: Try this remove return null; in doInBackground() and try once.

Comment: after i remove return null , occur error: missing return  statement

Comment: okay keep that line. and before doing null check, please put a break point and check whether "file_uri" is null or not if its null check why its null?

Answer (score 0):

if you see , you can take photos with the front camera, but the app will crash if you take them with the back camera

the solution is here

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
```

change bitmap.compress from 100 , to 75

this should fix the problem.